# Layer thickness measurement

Tags: optics, reflection, experimental-technique, lenses

I am interested to measure the thickness of the coating on a mirror (e.g. in the picture below). What are the available and best way of measuring it? What will be the solution in case of multiple layer coating on the same mirror how we could measure the thickness of all layers?

[image]

Comment: Almost certainly some kind of reflective interference technique is in order here, but I've never done that kind of work so I'd be starting from first principles. I believe we have some members who have done related work and may know the canonical answer.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly suggestion, but: is there a part number or serial number written on the element? Alternately, does the person who bought it remember what it is? In either case, you can talk to the manufacturer, as they tend to have this information available for those who ask.

Comment: If you knew what the coating was and so its refractive index (eg MgF2) you could estimate the thickness just from the angle you see the magenta in white light.

Comment: lets assume if I dont have any details about the coating and its R.I in that case is there any experimental technqiue to measure the thickness ?

Comment: YuZe Do you understand what @Martin was proposing? I mean, how it would work? Any interference based method is going to depend on the same physics, so if you don't *know* that physics you should definitely say so.

Comment: @dmckee Yes I understand what Martin suggested. I need to know the coating material for this right ? As I mentioned If I dont know whats the coating material and its refractive index. Is there any method to do such thickness measurment ?

Comment: Well, you need to know the index of refraction; knowing the material would tell you that but the alternative is to make a precision measurement of [Brewster's angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle).

Comment: Kindly mention any established experimental technique ?

Comment: Extremely hard to get without a destructive technique (i.e. specimen preparation for SEM or even TEM...). However, if you know the materials in the filter, you could know their refractive index and use Elipsometry to estimate their thickness (but it also a very difficult technique)

Comment: You can use polarized light and different wavelengths to do this.  If there is more than one coating I don't know if it is possible.  With a single coating by measuring over wavelengths, and using polarization you can actually measure the dielectric tensor, which will give you the index of refraction.

Answer (score 3):

Use an ellipsometer.  It's a common tool in semi-conductor processing and thin layer coating specialists for optics.  It uses polarized light and measures the relative change in polarization angle with depth.  From this you can get index, thickness of a layer stack.

Answer (score 0):

The color you see is an example of *strong reflection*. Light reflecting of the top surface interferes with light that traveled through the coating, reflected, and traveled back through the coating. The wavelength of the light that you see is based on constructive interference between these two...

First, it will be helpful to know at least whether the index of refraction is greater or less than the index of refraction of the glass. If $n_{f} < n_{g}$, then the light wave will flip over (or shift by 180 degrees), otherwise it won't.

If it doesn't shift by 180 degrees, then twice the thickness of the film will equal the wavelength of the strongly reflected light ***in the film***. If it does shift, then twice the thickness will equal half the wavelength, also in the film. You can determine the wavelength of the light in air, but it will be difficult to solve your problem without knowing the index of the film.

Presumably, there could be strong reflection at each interface in the case of multiple films. You wouldn't likely see all the colors, but if you use a spectrometer, it would probably be possible to resolve peaks at different wavelengths. The problem still remains of determining the index of refraction.